# Maximum and minimum values of $x + y$ given that $~~x^2+4y^2 \leq 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum values of $~x + y~$ with respect to the constraints $~~x^2+4y^2\leq 1.$

**My Attempt:**
Let us assume $~~f(x,y)=x+y~~$ and $~~g(x,y)=x^2+4y^2-1.$
Now Consider a function $~~L(x,y,k)=f+kg.$
Now notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0 \implies & 1+2xk=0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0 \implies & 1+8yk=0.
\end{align*}
Now from here I can conclude $~~x,y,k \neq 0.$ But I am not able to find the maximum and minimum values of $~~f$.

Comment: You need to solve for $x, y$ using those two equations and $x^2 + 4y^2 =1$.

Comment: You're maximizing a function $f(x, y)$ on a region (the region happens to be an ellipse). Since the function is smooth, you need to look only at two spots: (a) where the function has a local maximum (that is, both partial derivatives are zero) and (b) on the boundaries of the region (that is to say, on the border of the ellipse.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I was just about to post the solution given in the deleted answer -- why was is deleted?

Comment: You can write x,y as function of k and then compute the derivative of L(k), but it is not the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is valid on the boundary. But you're right,  there are no critical points in the interior.

Now you know $2xk=-1=8yk$. Since $k\neq 0$, we get $x=4y$. With $x^2+4y^2=1$ you get $(4y)^2+4y^2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=a\cos\phi$ and $2y=a\sin\phi$ for some $|a|\le1$. We just need to find maximum and minimum values of $a\cos\phi+\frac a2\sin\phi$.

Maximizing with respect to $\phi$ gives $\pm\sqrt{a^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}=\pm a\sqrt{\frac54}$. Taking $a=\pm1$, we get maximum and minimum to be $\pm\frac{\sqrt5}2$.